# vb.net System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled

Tags: mysql, asp.net, vb.net

I'm new to VB.NET. I have made a program for displaying an Excel file in a gridDataView and export it to a MySQL database.
But im getting this warning:

> "System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException was unhandled"

Can somebody help?

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    Try
        Dim cn As New OleDbConnection("provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=C:\Users\a.malibate\Desktop\test.xls; Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;")
        cn.Open()
        Dim da As New OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", cn)
        Dim dt As New DataTable
        da.Fill(dt)
    Catch ex As OleDbException
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try

    'setting the datagrid view
    With DataGridView1
        .AllowUserToAddRows() = False
        .BorderStyle() = BorderStyle.None
        .Columns(0).HeaderText = "Id"
        .Columns(1).HeaderText = "Name"
        .Columns(1).AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill
    End With

    'clearing memory

End Sub


Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnSave.Click
    BtnSave.Enabled = False
    Application.DoEvents()

    Dim cn As New SqlConnection("server=LENEL;database=PENSION;Integrated Security=SSPI")
    cn.Open()
    Dim cm As New SqlCommand
    With cm
        .Connection = cn
        For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            .CommandText = "insert into member_temporary values('" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value & "','" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value & "')"
            .ExecuteNonQuery()
        Next
    End With

    cm.Dispose()
    cm = Nothing
    With cn
        .Close()
        .Dispose()
    End With
    cn = Nothing

    MsgBox("Done")

    BtnSave.Enabled = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this

```
For i As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
```

to this

```
For i As Integer = 1 To DataGridView1.RowCount
```

There is no row 0 in datagridview. It goes from 1 up to row count.